# SQL syntax compatibility with MS Access

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

Could you help me please?
This is to create views on the G-NAF data (Australian addresses database, publicly available at https://data.gov.au/data/dataset/geocoded-national-address-file-g-naf). I managed to get all the tables in but can not execute the VIEW.
I realised e.g. that in MS Access SQL one can not use "numeric" but has to use "number".
I will appreciate help on this, I need to convert a SQL syntax to MS Access syntax and I don't know how.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW ADDRESS_VIEW

AS

SELECT
AD.ADDRESS_DETAIL_PID as ADDRESS_DETAIL_PID,
AD.STREET_LOCALITY_PID as STREET_LOCALITY_PID,
AD.LOCALITY_PID as LOCALITY_PID,
AD.BUILDING_NAME as BUILDING_NAME,

AD.LOT_NUMBER_PREFIX as LOT_NUMBER_PREFIX,
AD.LOT_NUMBER as LOT_NUMBER,
AD.LOT_NUMBER_SUFFIX as LOT_NUMBER_SUFFIX,

FTA.NAME as FLAT_TYPE,
AD.FLAT_NUMBER_PREFIX as FLAT_NUMBER_PREFIX,
AD.FLAT_NUMBER as FLAT_NUMBER,
AD.FLAT_NUMBER_SUFFIX as FLAT_NUMBER_SUFFIX,

LTA.NAME as LEVEL_TYPE,
AD.LEVEL_NUMBER_PREFIX as LEVEL_NUMBER_PREFIX,
AD.LEVEL_NUMBER as LEVEL_NUMBER,
AD.LEVEL_NUMBER_SUFFIX as LEVEL_NUMBER_SUFFIX,

AD.NUMBER_FIRST_PREFIX as NUMBER_FIRST_PREFIX,
AD.NUMBER_FIRST as NUMBER_FIRST,
AD.NUMBER_FIRST_SUFFIX as NUMBER_FIRST_SUFFIX,
AD.NUMBER_LAST_PREFIX as NUMBER_LAST_PREFIX,
AD.NUMBER_LAST as NUMBER_LAST,
AD.NUMBER_LAST_SUFFIX as NUMBER_LAST_SUFFIX,

SL.STREET_NAME as STREET_NAME,
SL.STREET_CLASS_CODE as STREET_CLASS_CODE,
SCA.NAME as STREET_CLASS_TYPE,
SL.STREET_TYPE_CODE as STREET_TYPE_CODE,
SL.STREET_SUFFIX_CODE as STREET_SUFFIX_CODE,
SSA.NAME as STREET_SUFFIX_TYPE,

L.LOCALITY_NAME as LOCALITY_NAME,

ST.STATE_ABBREVIATION as STATE_ABBREVIATION,

AD.POSTCODE as POSTCODE,

ADG.LATITUDE as LATITUDE,
ADG.LONGITUDE as LONGITUDE,
GTA.NAME as GEOCODE_TYPE,

AD.CONFIDENCE as CONFIDENCE,

AD.ALIAS_PRINCIPAL as ALIAS_PRINCIPAL,
AD.PRIMARY_SECONDARY as PRIMARY_SECONDARY,

AD.LEGAL_PARCEL_ID as LEGAL_PARCEL_ID,

AD.DATE_CREATED as DATE_CREATED

FROM

ADDRESS_DETAIL AD 
LEFT JOIN FLAT_TYPE_AUT FTA ON AD.FLAT_TYPE_CODE=FTA.CODE
LEFT JOIN LEVEL_TYPE_AUT LTA ON AD.LEVEL_TYPE_CODE=LTA.CODE
JOIN STREET_LOCALITY SL ON AD.STREET_LOCALITY_PID=SL.STREET_LOCALITY_PID
LEFT JOIN STREET_SUFFIX_AUT SSA ON SL.STREET_SUFFIX_CODE=SSA.CODE
LEFT JOIN STREET_CLASS_AUT SCA ON SL.STREET_CLASS_CODE=SCA.CODE 
LEFT JOIN STREET_TYPE_AUT STA ON SL.STREET_TYPE_CODE=STA.CODE
JOIN LOCALITY L ON AD.LOCALITY_PID = L.LOCALITY_PID
JOIN ADDRESS_DEFAULT_GEOCODE ADG ON AD.ADDRESS_DETAIL_PID=ADG.ADDRESS_DETAIL_PID
LEFT JOIN GEOCODE_TYPE_AUT GTA ON ADG.GEOCODE_TYPE_CODE=GTA.CODE
LEFT JOIN GEOCODED_LEVEL_TYPE_AUT GLTA ON AD.LEVEL_GEOCODED_CODE=GLTA.CODE
JOIN STATE ST ON L.STATE_PID=ST.STATE_PID

WHERE 
AD.CONFIDENCE > -1
```

Comment: What is the error message you are getting?

Comment: why do you alias every column with the same name ?

Comment: So what is your problem, how can we help

Comment: I think that in access you need to add brackets to joins, someting like this maybe `FROM ((ADDRESS_DETAIL AD 
  LEFT JOIN FLAT_TYPE_AUT FTA ON AD.FLAT_TYPE_CODE=FTA.CODE)
  LEFT JOIN LEVEL_TYPE_AUT LTA ON AD.LEVEL_TYPE_CODE=LTA.CODE)`

Comment: Also Access has no `OR REPLACE` in `CREATE VIEW`. Recreate the view as query by using the query designer in Access. It will do the syntax for you. You can then still switch to SQL view and copy the SQL into a CREATE VIEW.

Answer (score 3):

Access requires nesting on joins, I think it's like this:

```
FROM (
    (
        (
            (
                (
                    (
                        (
                            (
                                (
                                    (
                                        (
                                            ADDRESS_DETAIL AD LEFT JOIN FLAT_TYPE_AUT FTA ON AD.FLAT_TYPE_CODE = FTA.CODE
                                            ) LEFT JOIN LEVEL_TYPE_AUT LTA ON AD.LEVEL_TYPE_CODE = LTA.CODE
                                        ) INNER JOIN STREET_LOCALITY SL ON AD.STREET_LOCALITY_PID = SL.STREET_LOCALITY_PID
                                    ) LEFT JOIN STREET_SUFFIX_AUT SSA ON SL.STREET_SUFFIX_CODE = SSA.CODE
                                ) LEFT JOIN STREET_CLASS_AUT SCA ON SL.STREET_CLASS_CODE = SCA.CODE
                            ) LEFT JOIN STREET_TYPE_AUT STA ON SL.STREET_TYPE_CODE = STA.CODE
                        ) INNER JOIN LOCALITY L ON AD.LOCALITY_PID = L.LOCALITY_PID
                    ) INNER JOIN ADDRESS_DEFAULT_GEOCODE ADG ON AD.ADDRESS_DETAIL_PID = ADG.ADDRESS_DETAIL_PID
                ) LEFT JOIN GEOCODE_TYPE_AUT GTA ON ADG.GEOCODE_TYPE_CODE = GTA.CODE
            ) LEFT JOIN GEOCODED_LEVEL_TYPE_AUT GLTA ON AD.LEVEL_GEOCODED_CODE = GLTA.CODE
        ) INNER JOIN STATE ST ON L.STATE_PID = ST.STATE_PID
    )
WHERE AD.CONFIDENCE > - 1
```

As pointed out by HansUp in comments below, Access also requires that "INNER" be specified (i.e. you can't just use "JOIN" alone) - so that has now been included above.

The formatting seen above isn't essential.

As noted by AussieAndy Access does not understand "OR REPLACE" so that needs to be removed from the first line. The balance of the view code should work as is but you could remove all the column aliases.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! I noticed that for the syntax to work I need to remove OR REPLACE . But even then the MS Access returned error "Syntax error in JOIN operation". I thought I will get  away with it by removing bracket BEFORE every JOIN in the syntax. But it dd not help much... Any further suggestion? BTW: in File -> Options -> Object Designers, I have ticked SQL Server Compatibel Syntax (ANSI 92). Not sure if this is helping...

Comment: Yes "or replace" won't work in Access, I forgot that. Perhaps you should attempt to build this view via the gui?

Comment: Access SQL does not accept just `JOIN` as a synonym for `INNER JOIN` --- you must explicitly specify the join type.

Comment: Thank you once again guys!!!! Appreciate very much your help!!! Once I have replaced ```JOIN``` with ```INNER JOIN``` the query ran perfect and I got my complete view of the database...

Comment: g'day (Aussie to Aussie) I have tweaked the answer to include the notes from you and @HansUp - as they definitely add to the answer. Thanks.